# Discrepancy between SPX and SPY call premiums

Tags: options

SPX is usually around 10x that of SPY. SPY is at 217 means SPX is roughly 2165 to 2175. I understand that one is an ETF and the other just 'tracks', SPY gives out dividends, SPY is more liquid, etc.

However, for example, for Sept 2 expiry the call premiums are as follows (both of these are PM settled):

```
Call SPY @218 = $0.59

Call SPX @2180 = $4.1
```

I would have expected SPX to be around >= $5.5
Can any experienced traders explain the discrepancy?

Answer (score 2):

Some Factors in play:

- (MOST IMPORTANT) Dividend yield, if there was no dividend on SPY call value would go up to about ~0.50 USD
- Liquidity premium, if two assets are identical in every way except liquidity, more liquid asset has a higher value to investors. However in this case I think the liquidity premium is more an issue for the market maker than anyone.
- Costs, I doubt costs are equal for Futures trading of SPX vs ETF Trading of SPY, driving costs up. This has to do with the cost of hedging for the market maker.

Comment: The problem with the dividend theory is that SPY is predicted to go ex-dividend on September 16, two weeks after the option expires on September 2. The dividend is predicted to be about 1.087